# Can not access kubernetes master from the container of pods according DNS

Tags: dns, docker, kubernetes

I use DNS in kubernetes. and test result like:

```
core@core-1-86 ~ $ kubectl exec busybox -- nslookup kubernetes
Server:    10.100.0.10
Address 1: 10.100.0.10

Name:      kubernetes
Address 1: 10.100.0.1
```

And then I entried to busybox container, and ping kubernetes, like:

```
core@core-1-86 ~ $ kubectl exec -it busybox sh
/ # ping kubernetes
PING kubernetes (10.100.0.1): 56 data bytes
^C
--- kubernetes ping statistics ---
55 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
/ #
```

if I ping another ip , it ok!

```
/ # ping 10.12.1.85
PING 10.12.1.85 (10.12.1.85): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.12.1.85: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.262 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.1.85: seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.218 ms
^C
--- 10.12.1.85 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.218/0.240/0.262 ms
/ #
```

who can help me and tell me why?

Comment: And How to find kubernetes master from DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kubernetes service is a virtual IP and doesn't currently handle ICMP requests (see #[2259](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2259)). You should be able to verify connectivity to the kubernetes service using a TCP connection, e.g. `curl https://kubernetes/`.

Comment: Yes, doesn't currently handle ICMP requests as you say.
I use curl and can get response from other domain, like:
    

    root@hello-world:/# curl http://monitoring-influxdb:8086
    404 page not found
    root@hello-world:/# curl http://kubernetes
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: kubernetes

but could not resolve host: kubernetes

Comment: Nope, the response is the same to curl kubernetes.




root@hello-world:/# curl https://kubernetes
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: kubernetes

Comment: but if I curl `https://10.100.0.1`; , the result like follow, Is this mean I can access the master from the container of the pod ? 
`curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` `More details here: curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html curl performs SSL` `certificate verification by default, using a "bundle" of Certificate Authority` `(CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default bundle file isn't adequate, you` `can specify an alternate file using the --cacert option –`

Comment: For the certificates that we generate via the shell scripts, we add the service IP to the list of subject alternate names (SANs) that are valid. If you create a cluster on GCE, for instance, you'd be able to curl the kubernetes service IP without getting a certificate warning. You can either pass `--insecure` to curl or re-generate a server certificate for your apiserver that includes `10.100.0.1` as a SAN.

Comment: Yes, I can use `curl --insecure`
`root@hello-world:/# curl https://10.100.0.1 --insecure`
`Unauthorized`

Comment: You might be using a container that has broken DNS resolution - are you based on Alpine, by chance?